# Angular styles problem (primeng - primeflex)

Tags: angular, styles, primeng, primeflex

I am using primeflex, and in begin all go good, but now... i dont know what happen. Suddenly breaks.

This styles arent catching by the elements of the html.

The first example of grid system dont work:

```
<div class="p-grid">
<div class="p-col-4">4</div>
<div class="p-col">1 </div>
<div class="p-col">1 </div>
<div class="p-col">1 </div>
<div class="p-col">1 </div>
<div class="p-col">1 </div>
<div class="p-col">1 </div>
<div class="p-col">1 </div>
<div class="p-col">1 </div>
```

[image]

But, 1 hour moving the css to one site to another, i notice that the css is really there. I try this, changing the selector:

[image]

And magic, begin to work:

[image]

That selector, the "p-X" is the problem.

I suppose some in my modules, my angular or something miss some configuration. But dont know what. This is a project test, i will make another one from the beginning, but will be usefull to know what happen when the real project launch.

I can give the other code (angular.json, modules and that...) but i think that the problem isnt there (its works yesterday).

Comment: What version of PrimeFlex do you use? I think that this is the problem. In the last version of PrimeFlex, you have to use col whereas in other versions, you have to use p-col (https://www.primefaces.org/primeflex/gridsystem)

Comment: I have installed this:     "primeflex": "^3.0.1", "primeicons": "^4.1.0",  "primeng": "^12.0.1". But in the beginning its works :( Rare, rare, rare

Comment: I create a new project ant put primeflex 2.0.0. You are right, Alba. In 2.0 works the selector p-col. I dont understand how its work me in the past... I go to holidays, perhaps its updated automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirm that the problem is the version of primeflex.

The new version (3.0) uses another names for the selector classes (col-X). In (2.0) uses other (p-col-X).

The link of the documentation in primeng are both (3.0 and 2.0, care looking). This is 3.0:

https://www.primefaces.org/primeflex/gridsystem

Thanks to Alba.